# Do a range validation with List<Dictionary<string, List<double>>>

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a section "UnsecuredConfiguration" in my json file like below

```
"UnsecuredConfiguration": {
  "WA": [1,5],
  "NSW": [ 6, 100 ]
}
```

Now if i get a parameter value as 4, I need to check if that value exists in the string array for example in [1,5] and should return "WA", if it matches inside range validation.

I succeeded in getting this json value in my options and read inside a  dictionary like below

```
List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>> unsecuredData = new List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>();
```

Now i am need a linq query to work the magic like

```
 where (a.Value1 >= pdata && a.Value2 <= pdata)
```

> Also appreciate any better methods to do so

I had found a way with foreach loop which satisfy my requirement

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> item in config)
        {
            if (someKeys >= item.Value[0] && someKeys <= item.Value[1])
            {
                state = item.Key;
            }
        }
```

I am just hoping we can convert the same to a LINQ which will be much appreciated.

Comment: Parse the data into a more usable form.

Comment: what if doesn't match?

Comment: Is this the only content in the json file or more contents?

Comment: I had read the values using _config = Options.Create(configuration.GetSection("RuleConfiguration").Get<RuleConfiguration>()); :)

Comment: `List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>` does not fit your JSON structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `config` is a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` you can get your desired dictionary key as  follows

```
int someKeys = ...;
var key = config.Where(x=> x.Value.Count >= 2 && x.Value[0] <= someKeys && x.Value[1] >= someKeys)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.Key;
```

This will return the key fitting range, or `null` if no fitting range is found.

Comment: Wow that was the exact thing i was looking for!! Thanks mate

Comment: Can u please help me here too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920962/find-the-largest-income-in-employee-list-and-if-more-than-1-person-have-same-sal

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> unsecuredData = ...;

string parameter = "4";
if (int.TryParse(parameter, out int pdata) && unsecuredData.Any(pair => pair.ContainsKey("WA") && pair["WA"].Count > 1
    && int.TryParse(pair["WA"][0], out int start) && pdata >= start
    && int.TryParse(pair["WA"][1], out int end) && pdata <= end))
{
    //valid...
}
```

Comment: Wow Amazing. I need to map to a Dictionary<string, List<string>> config rather than List and results like ([NSW, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]}) where key is "NSW" and Values is an array of Value[0] = "1" and Value[1] = "5". The range between values should get Key. Does that helps?

Comment: @RX100: I don't follow. I gave you an example. Just replace "WA" with whatever your key is?